# How to find what toolboxes (not installed) are necessaries to execute a matlab script?

Tags: matlab

Hi I saw this command that should allow to find toolboxes dependencies:

`matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`

however such command will also list the installed toolboxes, which is not what I want.
Is there a way to find out what are the toolboxes that are not installed but needed to execute a given script?

From the documtation

`[fList, pList] = matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts(files)` also returns a list of the MathWorks® products possibly required to run the program files specified by files.

> If you use the matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts function on
>   MATLAB code that you received, plist only includes the required
>   toolboxes that are installed on your system. In this case, plist can
>   be incomplete.

So the command will list the "required" but that are "installed".

Answer (score 1):

I can not test it because I have all toolboxes available, but something of the likes:

```
[files,plist]= matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts('myfile');
toolboxRequiredAndMissing(plist);


function toolboxRequiredAndMissing(plist)
v=ver;
for ii=2:length(plist)
    found=false;
    for jj=1:length(v)
        found= strcmp(plist(ii).Name,v(jj).Name);
        if found
           break
        end
    end
    if (~found)
       disp(['Toolbox required and missing: ' plist(ii).Name]);
    end
end
end
```

This does not consider versions.

Comment: Not 100% sure it's working, it is listing as missing dependencies `MATLAB Distributed Computing Server`, but when I run the code I have the error regards a `Curve Fitting` toolbox.

Comment: You might want to remove the rows in `plist` where `plist.Certain == 0`.

Comment: @Wolfie just "may", as as far as I understand, they may still be required, even if MATLAB is not certain

Comment: @user8469759 It works for me. If I delete specific `v` toolbox info, this code outputs those as needed. What "is it listing"? What error do you get? All this is new info

Comment: There's no error in your script, when I run it I get the output: `Toolbox required and missing: MATLAB Distributed Computing Server`, but when I run the script I got from a git repository I get an error because of the missing toolbox I mentioned.

Comment: Your script should when the script `myfile` calls other scripts inside, right?

Comment: @user8469759 maybe not, depends on `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`

Comment: Well, that does output all the files, so I guess it works recursively.

Comment: What's `v` in your update? (second for loop in the function `toolboxRequiredAndMissing`)

Answer (score 0):

That appears to be the case, which is huge letdown because I'm in the situation where I'm trying to figure out for a new project I'm on what the full set of toolbox dependencies are *prior* to going and trying to install them. The alternative is to take the runtime failures piecewise until you discover all the dependencies.

My first missing discovered dependency is...

```
To use 'downsample', the following product must be licensed, installed, and enabled:
  Signal Processing Toolbox
```

But when I run `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts` on my files the pList only displays a dependency on Matlab which is useless.

```
pList = 

  struct with fields:

             Name: 'MATLAB'
          Version: '9.3'
    ProductNumber: 1
          Certain: 1
```

The thing that's incredibly dissatisfying here is that the runtime is smart enough to detect what toolbox is required but the tooling is not smart enough to populate the pList with that same information.

I think the workaround is to have a colleague run this command on their local setup which is a known working environment and have them communicate the results of the pList over to you.